# How to return a JSON to ajax in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, yii

I want to do a web project using Yii2, and I want to return a JSON to AJAX. I have used `json_encode()` and `Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;`, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my action:

```
public function actionAbout(){
  Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
  return json_encode(["test"=> 1]);
}
```

Here is my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  // dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'user': 'A'
  },
  url: "?site/about",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

But it returns this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>....
```

still a html. How to solve it?

Comment: Works fine for me. Although you shouldn't `json_encode` the array yourself when setting the response type to `FORMAT_JSON`. What's the complete response?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`return json_encode(["test"=> 1]);`

shouldn't you be echoing it like this

`echo json_encode(["test"=> 1]);`

plus if you ARE setting the `Yii::$app->response->format` to `FORMAT_JSON` then you do not need to encode the array to `JSON` just return the array.

```
return ['test'=>1];
```